# Overlay layer causes scroll bar to appear

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a page where I use jQuery UI. I also use modal dialogs, which use an overlay layer (**.ui-widget-overlay**). For some reason when an overlay appears i get a horizontal scroll bar, which disappears as soon as the overlay is closed. I have no idea what's causing it, since the overlay is not tied in with the rest of the page...

Would appreciate if someone can take a look. To trigger it, just refresh the page, it's on load.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure.  When it is loading the page, it thinks the page width is 1927 (on my screen), when it is in fact 1903. This is adding the scroll-bar, as the ui-widget-overlay gets set to width 100% = 1927. Try removing the `onload="self.focus()"` from the body.  You could also try delaying the load of the dialog by a few milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks I'll try both. I have another page that uses the same overlay with a very similar layout and it does not have that problem. It just drives me nuts...

Comment: It turns out some of my code was read after the overlay was loaded. By moving that code higher, the problem went away. Thanks for the tip where to look.